# New to Javascript. What is wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm relatively new too javascript and can't get this code to work. I've googled how to use down down menus, but whenever i try to run this code it doesn't seem to work. whenever i set form.value = "net", the if statement works, so why doesn't it work when comparing form.value = "test"?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" value="Name here" id="testing" />
</form>
<br/>
<select id="inout">
    <option value="net" selected="selected">next</option>
    <option value="test">test</option>
</select>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var form;
    var actual;
    form = document.getElementById('inout');

    form.addEventListener('change', test (), false);

    function test()
    {


        if(form.value == "test")
        {
            window.location.href = 'index.html';
        }
    }

</script>
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

</html>
```

Edit: Thanks guys, this was really frustrating.

Comment: If you have some c background.. think of `test()` as a function call .. which executes the function right away .. and `test` as a function pointer .. which points to a function.. what you need is `test`

Answer (score 3):

in `form.addEventListener('change', test (), false);` you are calling `test` and passing its return value (`undefined`) as a callback to `addEventListener`.

[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) requires a function as its second argument. Syntactically, that means removing the parentheses after the function name in your code:

```
form.addEventListener('change', test, false);
```

You can understand that line as saying:

> Whenever a 'change' event bubbles up to the element referenced by `form`, call the function referenced by `test`.

Comment: A reference to that function so when the event occurs, it can call that function using that reference passed to it!

Answer (score 2):

change this.

```
form.addEventListener('change', test (), false);
```

to this

```
form.addEventListener('change', test, false);
```

When you write test() it calls the function immediately not on change event.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your listener up improperly.

`form.addEventListener('change', test (), false);`

Notice how `test` has `()` after it? That means you have already run the function (which returns nothing). This is what your program actually does:

`form.addEventListener('change', undefined, false);`

So every time you change the drop down nothing happens at all. It needs to look like this:

`form.addEventListener('change', test, false);`

When the form changes, the function `test` will run.